# Is there a way to add a PHP IF statement in an SQL Update Statement

Tags: php, mysql

This is from a profile update page; so if a person changes their `email2` from tom@aol.com to tommy@aol.com I want the `email2_verified` to be reset to `unverified`

My code is..

```
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE user SET uname=%s,email=%s, email2=%s  WHERE `uid`=%s && `pass_code`=%s",
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['uname'], "text"), 
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['email2'], "text"),
            GetSQLValueString($_POST['uid'], "int"),
            GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
```

I also have a field `email2_verified`; The goal is.. if `email2` has changed I want it `unverified`;
Is there a way to ad an if statement in an sql statement that would work like the following code..?

```
    $updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE user SET uname=%s,email=%s, email2=%s  
    WHERE `uid`=%s && `pass_code`=%s,email2_verified=%s",


    if($_POST['email2']){ // **has not changed** 
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['uname'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"), 
    }        

    if($_POST['email2']){ //**has changed**                
     GetSQLValueString("unverified","text"),
    }

    GetSQLValueString($_POST['email2'], "text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_POST['uid'], "int"),
    GetSQLValueString($password, "text"));
```

I'm guessing (the most laymen way is)I may have to create a select statement that runs before the update statement and

```
    if htmlentities($post['email2']) <> $row['email2']
            use update statement 1 
    else
            use update statement 2
```

is that the best way or is there a php function I am unaware of that can do it on the fly?

Comment: your code is very badly formatted :D

Comment: What do you mean by this bold "has changed"?

Comment: Its standard formatting from dreamweaver.. I'm not a pro like most here :)

Comment: This is from a profile update page; so if a person changes their email2 from tom@aol.com to tommy@aol.com I want the email2_verified to be reset to 'unverified'

Comment: Why are you using sprintf to produce a SQL query? And why are you calling a GetSQLValueString global function when all recent versions of PHP come with a perfectly fine and injection-proof PDO MySQL driver? And why do you want to run PHP inside a SQL query?

You should wire your PHP to determine which SQL query to run.

Comment: use PDO! and no, if you make condition at php level either the condition changes the parameters you put into your query or you need to create anther query for each condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a trigger in MySQL.

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER detect_email_change BEFORE UPDATE ON user FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    IF NEW.email2 != OLD.email2 THEN
      SET NEW.email2_verified = "unverified";
    END IF;
  END;//

DELIMITER ;
```

Then you just update the email2 field and the trigger will take care of the rest.

Answer (score 2):

You could reach this by working with prepared statements.

Means: you would create a query with placeholders. Then you can write something like this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");

if(condition) {
    $stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
} else {
    $stmt->bind_param('abc', dbc, $language2, $officia2l, $percent2);
}
$stmt->execute;
```

check this link for more informations about statements:

https://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 0):

Just do that (*I'm using your code*):

```
<?php   

  if ($_POST['email2']) { 
    // has changed

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET uname=%s,email=%s, email2=%s " .  
           ",email2_verified=%s " . 
           "WHERE `uid`=%s && `pass_code`=%s";

    $updateSQL = sprintf(
      $sql,
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['uname'], "text"),
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
      GetSQLValueString("unverified","text")
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['email2'], "text"),
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['uid'], "int"),
      GetSQLValueString($password, "text")
    );



  } else {

    $sql = "UPDATE user SET uname=%s,email=%s, email2=%s " .  
           "WHERE `uid`=%s && `pass_code`=%s";

    $updateSQL = sprintf(
      $sql,
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['uname'], "text"),
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['email2'], "text"),
      GetSQLValueString($_POST['uid'], "int"),
      GetSQLValueString($password, "text")
    );

  }
```

If you want a SQL solution, use the [Kouber Saparev answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21319478/791668).